# The chromatic number of a triangle-free graph.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a triangle-free graph. Prove that $$\chi(G)\leq3\left\lceil\dfrac{\Delta(G)+1}{4}\right\rceil$$

What's the relationship between the chromatic number and the maximum degree of a triangle-free graph $G$. I got a hint that I could apply the Brook's Theorem but I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Note that (for $n\ge 3$) the inequality holds for every odd cycle that is not a triangle and that furthemore, a triangle-free graph is certainly not a complete graph.

Comment: @Studentmath: please elaborate. How does this help to show that e.g. a triangle-free graph with maximum degree 23 only requires 18 colors.

Comment: I still can't figure this out. Can anyone post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

First take a partition of $V$ into $k=\lceil(\Delta+1)/4\rceil$ classes $V_1,\dots,V_k$ that minimizes the number of monochromatic edges. Note $\Delta<4k.$ By the pigeonhole principle, for each vertex $v\in V_j,$ there is some class $V_i$ such that at most three of the at most $\Delta$ neighbors of $v$ lie in $V_i.$ By minimality, putting $v$ in $V_i$ instead of $V_j$ cannot decrease the number of monochromatic edges, so $v$ has at most three neighbors in $V_j.$ In other words $\Delta(G[V_j])\leq 3$ for each $j.$

By Brooks' theorem and the triangle-free assumption, each $G[V_j]$ has a 3-coloring. Using disjoint color sets for each $V_j$ we get a $3k$-coloring of $G$ as required.

A history of this result is given in the introduction to ["Chromatic number, girth and maximal degree" by B. Bollobás](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X78901024). Improving the bound is an [open problem](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/bounding_the_chromatic_number_of_triangle_free_graphs_with_fixed_maximum_degree).

Comment: Do you mean $k = \left \lceil{(\Delta + 1)/4}\right \rceil$?

Comment: @ensbana: I did mean that, thank you

Comment: "Improving the bound is an open problem" is a misleading statement (also, the link is dead). Getting all the way to the conjectured bound $\chi(G) \le \frac12\Delta(G)+2$ is an open problem. But Kostochka proved $\chi(G) \le \frac23\Delta(G)+2$ in 1978, which is already better than $3\left\lceil\frac{\Delta(G)+1}{4}\right\rceil$. See [this page](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/regs/chitrifree.html) for an overview of what is known.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If there exists a partition $V(G)$ into $k$ subsets $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ such that $\chi(G_i)\leq \ell$ for every $i$ (where $G_i$ is the subgraph of $G$ induced by $V_i$), then $\chi(G)\leq \ell k$.

Comment: I still can't figure this out. Could you elaborate? Thanks.